# Erro no python usando Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Então eu estou fazendo um pequeno programa para as mães de alunos para calcular a media de seus filhos 
porem hoje fui fazer uma gui com o Tkinter e so acho video antigo para fazer um texto ou no caso uma label

Esse é o meu codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

win.title("Calculadora de media")
win.geometry('600x500')
win.resizable(False, False)

Texto1 = Label(win,text = "Test")
Texto1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

quando vou executa-lo da esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cauã Wernek\Desktop\pythonbook\calculadora de media\gui\pythongui.py", line 9, in <module>
    Texto1 = Label(win,text = "Test")
NameError: name 'Label' is not defined
```

Oque eu errei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batata, o erro ocorre por conta do `Label` que também faz parte do `import tkinter`, logo ele também precisa ter o `tk.` antes de usado (pois foi assim que você *"apelidou"* o import), veja abaixo a correção:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

win.title("Calculadora de media")
win.geometry('600x500')
win.resizable(False, False)

Texto1 = tk.Label(win,text = "Test")
Texto1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```